# JSON data and DBIx::Class - how can I store data directly?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbix-class

I have a Postgres database with a JSON column, for which I'd like to do something like this:

```
use lib './lib';
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex);
use Data::Dump qw/dump/;

use Foo; # isa 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

$f = Foo->connect('dbi:Pg:database=mydb');

my $i = $f->resultset('People')->create({ id => md5_hex(rand() . 'some string') });
$i->insert;
$i->data({ name => 'john', surname => 'doe', birthday => '04/07/1976'});

#--------------------------------
# this is the important bit
# assigning to the HoH directly
#--------------------------------
$i->data->{books} = ['1984', 'Wuthering heights'];
$i->update;
```

Foo::People looks like this:

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 0, size => 32 },
  "data",
  { data_type => "json", is_nullable => 1, accessor  => '_data', },
);

__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key(qw/id/);

use JSON::XS;
use Data::Dump qw/dump/;

sub data {
    my ($self, $value) = @_;
    if(@_ > 1) {
        my $value = encode_json($value);
        $self->_data($value);
    }
    $value = decode_json($self->_data());
    return $value;
}
```

However this does not work - the only thing that does is store the hash in a temporary value, change it, and then store it again, like this:

```
my $v = $i->data;
$v->{books} = ['1984', 'Wuthering heights'];
$i->data($v)    
$i->update;
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is an InflateColumn like https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::InflateColumn::Serializer::JSYNC.

You can also easily write one yourself.

Don't forget that DBIC just generates column accessors for you when you call add_column and their names are configurable so can rename them an call them from your own aceessor method.

Or you use Moo(se) method modifiers.

Comment: There are good examples in the [DBIx::Class::InflateColumn docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/InflateColumn.pod)

Comment: Thanks @abraxxa - this solved the problem but only partially. See my answer below. Appreciate anyway . you set me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Inflating/deflating the column like in abraxxa's answer works fine, but I still have to update the column explicitly, otherwise the assignments to the dereferenced field do not get stored.

I ended up adding an attribute to the column, and adding a `before` Moose hook on update like so:

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
             "id" => { data_type => "varchar", is_nullable => 0, size => 32 },
             "data" => {
                  data_type => "json",
                  is_nullable => 1,
                  always_update => 1
             },
);
```

and

```
before 'update' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my %c = $self->get_columns;
    for (grep { $self->result_source->column_info($_)->{always_update} } keys %c) {
        $self->make_column_dirty($_);
    }
};
```

this way I do not need to call updates on the `data` column explicitly every time.

I don't know if this is a bad idea - comments welcome.

Comment: It was a bad design decision of DBIC's update method to take parameters which change the column values because it circumvents the column accessor methods. It is therefore recommended to not use this api and always modify result (row) objects using their accessors and ensure update throws an exception when passed column values with for example a before or around method modifier.